# Docker container not shutting down in Swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

On my docker swarm cluster, when I perform a `docker stack deploy` with a new version of my service's image or do a `docker service update --force`, the old containers of the service(s) get desired state SHUTDOWN, they remain with a current state running.

However, they don't seem te be actually running, I can't do anything with them, `docker logs`, `docker inspect`, `docker exec`, ... nothing.

The only way to get rid of them is to restart the docker daemon.

What would you consider look at to try to understand and fix this recurring issue ?

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue a few days ago: Turned out, we had a logging-driver configured, but the logging-server was not available. We stopped using this anyway, but forgot to remove the configuration from the service:

```yaml
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        fluentd-async-connect: "true"
```

Removing this configuration fixed the issue for future containers. Old instances were still hanging around, but restarting Docker helped.